# Is this the correct order for BFS and DFS?

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Below I have a tree and I need to list the order of marking vertices as visited for both DFS and BFS. I have my list below but just wondering if I did it correctly. It starts from 0.

[image: S]

Comment: Looks ok to me. If depends of course in how you pic the neighbors of each node.  For example BFS could also yield 0641523.

Answer (score 0):

The question says you have a tree, but this is not a tree; it is a graph. The answer therefore depends on whether this is an undirected graph or a directed graph. I suspect whoever created the diagram intended the graph to be directed, with vertical positioning indicating direction, but they should have made this clearer by using arrowheads to indicate the edge directions. As it is, it looks like edges coming into a node are at the top of it, and edges coming out of a node are at the bottom of it.

The correct order also depends on which order a node's neighbours are visited in. For DFS, this will depend on the implementation of DFS; a recursive DFS will usually visit children in ascending order, whereas an iterative DFS using a stack will sometimes visit in descending order (because the stack's LIFO behaviour means they'll be popped in reverse order), unless the children are pushed to the stack in reverse order.

Normally BFS will visit children in ascending order, and there is no particular reason an implementation of BFS would visit them in descending order (since a queue is FIFO, they are polled in the same order they're inserted into the queue).

---

If the graph is directed, then DFS order would be `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` if you visit children in ascending order, or (coincidentally) `0 6 5 4 2 3 1` if you visit children in descending order.

If you assumed the graph is directed, then your answer for DFS cannot be correct because it ends with `2 1 3`. If `3` isn't visited yet, then it should be visited immediately after `2`, before backtracking.

---

Alternatively, if the graph is undirected then DFS order would (coincidentally) be `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` if children are visited in ascending order, or (coincidentally) `0 6 5 4 2 3 1` if they are visited in descending order.

If you assumed the graph is undirected then your answer for DFS is inconsistent, because you start by going from node `0` to node `6` (i.e. descending order), but then when you reach node `2` you visit node `1` before node `3` (i.e. ascending order).

---

Your answer for BFS is correct whether the graph is directed or undirected.